# Android sms sending app runtime error

Tags: android, runtime-error

i am a totally new guy around here and i dont know whether its the right place to ask my silly doubts...but please help me guys...i coded a simple sms sending programe and its showing runtime errror..i dont knw how to debug it..plz help

```
    package com.smsProject;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.telephony.SmsManager;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    public class SmsProjectActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);



        buttonSend=(Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
        buttonSend.setOnClickListener(this);



    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     String msg=editTextmessage.getText().toString();
     String num=editTextnumber.getText().toString();
     SmsManager sms=SmsManager.getDefault();
     sms.sendTextMessage(num,null, msg,null,null);

     editTextmessage.setText("");
     editTextnumber.setText("");

    }
}
```

my main.xml file is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@drawable/jibin">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/msg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="Enter the message">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/num"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text|textPersonName" android:hint="Enter a  number"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send" />

</LinearLayout>
```

my exception catlog is

```
    01-31 20:40:43.587: W/dalvikvm(1593): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-31 20:40:43.607: E/AndroidRuntime(1593): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 20:40:43.607: E/AndroidRuntime(1593): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-31 20:40:47.936: W/InputManagerService(71): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 1593 uid 10038
01-31 20:43:45.129: D/SntpClient(71): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
01-31 20:48:45.130: D/SntpClient(71): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
01-31 20:49:43.546: W/dalvikvm(1638): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-31 20:49:43.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1638): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 20:49:43.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1638): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-31 20:49:47.227: W/InputManagerService(71): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 1638 uid 10038
01-31 20:53:45.137: D/SntpClient(71): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
01-31 20:58:45.151: D/SntpClient(71): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
01-31 21:03:45.156: D/SntpClient(71): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
01-31 21:08:45.167: D/SntpClient(71): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
01-31 21:13:45.177: D/SntpClient(71): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
01-31 21:18:45.178: D/SntpClient(71): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
01-31 21:23:45.187: D/SntpClient(71): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
01-31 21:28:45.187: D/SntpClient(71): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
01-31 21:33:45.196: D/SntpClient(71): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
01-31 21:38:45.199: D/SntpClient(71): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
01-31 21:43:45.207: D/SntpClient(71): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
01-31 21:48:45.211: D/SntpClient(71): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
01-31 21:52:31.657: W/dalvikvm(1758): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-31 21:52:31.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1758): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 21:52:31.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1758): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-31 21:53:45.216: D/SntpClient(71): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

Comment: Hello how you solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post the runtime [exception from logcat](http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2011/09/11/android-tutorial-7-how-to-debug-the-android-mobile-application-with-logcat/). Hard to say without that, but my guess is that you haven't requested the appropriate permissions, try adding this to the top-level `manifest` node of your manifest xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Comment: Thanks...Bu I have added the permissions.M y logcat is

Comment: Are you trying this on an emulator or real device? I would suggest trying this on a real device if you're not already.

Comment: Hmm I'm stumped, the last thing to make sure would be that your destination address is a valid phone number...and i would try searching around for "Address family not supported by protocol"